# Finding a gps location at a certain time given two points?

Tags: python, python-2.7, gps, geolocation, coordinate-systems

If I have two known locations and a known speed, how can I calculate the current position at distance d (in km)?

For example, given:

**Two gps locations in ES4236:**

```
37.783333, -122.416667   # San Francisco
32.715, -117.1625        # San Diego
```

Traveling at **1km/min** in a straight line (ignoring altitude)

**How can I find the gps coordinate at a certain distance?** A similar [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24427828) uses VincentyDistance in `geopy` to calculate the next point based on bearing and distance.

I guess, more specifically:

- How can I calculate the bearing between two gps points using `geopy`?
- Using VincentyDistance to get the next gps point by bearing and distance, how do I know if I have arrived at my destination, or if I should keep going? It doesn't need to be exactly on the destination to be considered being arrived. Maybe any point with a radius of .5 km of the destination is considered 'arrived'.

ie,

```
import geopy

POS1 = (37.783333, -122.416667)     # origin
POS2 = (32.715, -117.1625)          # dest

def get_current_position(d):
    # use geopy to calculate bearing between POS1 and POS2
    # then use VincentyDistance to get next coord

    return gps_coord_at_distance_d

# If current position is within .5 km of destination, consider it 'arrived'
def has_arrived(curr_pos):
    return True/False

d = 50     # 50 km
print get_current_position(d)
print has_arrived(get_current_position(d))
```

Comment: Duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24427828/calculate-point-based-on-distance-and-direction

Comment: @James Ah thanks, but that calculates the distance going north by 1km (by bearing) rather than towards a second point. Also I can't find any documentation about `VincentyDistance` in geopy, so I'm having a hard time seeing if it can calculate based on two points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, figured I'd come back to this question and give it my best shot given that it hasn't seen any other solutions. Unfortunately I can't test code right now, but I believe there is a solution to your problem using both geopy and geographiclib. Here goes.

From the terminal (possibly with sudo)

```
pip install geographiclib
pip install geopy
```

Now with Python

## Get Current Position

```
import geographiclib
from geopy import geopy.distance

# Get the first azimuth, which should be the bearing
bearing = geographiclib.WGS84.Inverse(37.783333, -122.416667, 32.715, -117.1625)[2]


# Now we use geopy to calculate the distance over time
dist = geopy.distance.VincentyDistance(kilometers = 1)
san_fran = geopy.Point(37.783333, -122.416667)

print dist.destination(point=san_fran, bearing=bearing)
```

## Has Arrived

```
def has_arrived(d):
    return geopy.distance.vincenty(curr_pos, (32.715, -117.1625)).kilometers < .5
```

Like I said, I unfortunately can't test this, but I believe this is correct. It's possible there will be some unit differences with the bearing calculation: [it calculates bearing off of North as seen here](http://geographiclib.sourceforge.net/html/python/geodesics.html). Sorry if this isn't exactly correct, but like I said since this hasn't received a response since I figured I may as well throw in what I know.

Comment: Thanks! There were some minor errors in the code, but overall you are correct. Do you think you could help with the `has_arrived()`? Given a distance (ie, km=100), how do I determine if that is within the destination radius? Also, can I specify in meters instead of km using VicentyDistance?

Comment: Unfortunately you can't specify meters. I'll add has_arrived to the answer

Comment: Something is wrong. The `dist.destination(point=san_fran, bearing=bearing)` is giving me the next gps point in the wrong direction. If I change it to `des.destination(point=san_diego, bearing=bearing)`, then it'll immediately jump to the destination.

Comment: Sorry, it turns out my bearing was wrong. `s12` was not what I thought it meant.