# Convert a gps coordinate to an lat lng format?

Tags: python, python-2.7, gps, coordinates, geopy

This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24427828/calculate-point-based-on-distance-and-direction) has returned a coordinate like this: `48 52m 0.0s N, 2 21m 0.0s E`.

But I want it something like `37.783333, -122.416667`.

ie:

```
import geopy
import geopy.distance

# Define starting point.
start = geopy.Point(48.853, 2.349)

# Define a general distance object, initialized with a distance of 1 km.
d = geopy.distance.VincentyDistance(kilometers = 1)

# Use the `destination` method with a bearing of 0 degrees (which is north)
# in order to go from point `start` 1 km to north.
print d.destination(point=start, bearing=0)

# ^^^ That prints "48 52m 0.0s N, 2 21m 0.0s E"
# How to get it to lat lng?
```

Also, I don't know the terminology. I think the coordinates I want are in 4236, but I don't know what `48 52m 0.0s N, 2 21m 0.0s E` is called.

Comment: What about x = d.destination(point=start, bearing=0)
print(x.latitude, x.longitude)?

Comment: @JesperFreesbug That worked. If you make an answer, I'll mark it correct. Although some terminology would be great too, so I can be more specific next time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sorry for not being able to provide you with the correct terminology :[ However, here is a possible solution for the code:

```
x = d.destination(point=start, bearing=0) 
print(x.latitude, x.longitude)
```